# Where to keep AWS SDK config credentials needed for an html page

Tags: amazon-web-services, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

I have a single HTML page that has all JavaScript logic inside it. I am using AWS SDK by importing it like:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.978.0.min.js"></script>
```

Whenever I try to make a call to AWS Secrets manager, I am getting `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config` because my page does not know my `accessKey` and `secretKeyId`.

If I add the following snippet in my code:

```
AWS.config.update({
   accessKeyId: "XXXXXXX",
   secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
})
```

Everything works as expected, however I am exposing my credentials to anyone that has access to that file. What is the best practise to store these credentials, how can I make sure I obtain them safely for my use case - a single HTML page?

Comment: just wondering - what are you using the secrets for? if you have a single HTML page, you will end up getting secret to the client anyway, which defeats the purpose. I can't think of a workflow where you would need a secret on a single HTML/JS page (without server component) even if it *were* possible. There are ways to generate short-lived URL, or user serverless capabilities of AWS (lambda) - but it will still be server-side code

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using AWS Cognito and authorize using IAM roles. You can check out AWS Amplify, for complete tutorials on how to set it up. It will be more effort but the only way to keep access keys out of your front-end code. Please, never compile your access key and secret key into your front-end.

I can imagine the investigation effort of my suggested approach might be to much, here is a quick approach to get you started using the AWS Management Console:

- Find the [AWS Cognito service](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=us-east-1#)
- Select Federated Identities
- Create New Identity pool

  - Add poolname
  - Tick the checkbox 'Enable access to unauthenticated identities'
  - Click 'save'
  - Now you can set up IAM roles for the Identity Pool, make sure
    to edit the unauthorized role policy to enable access to the required services.

```
// example policy document, allowing full access to all services. 
// never deploy this to production, only give access to services that are required.
// always adhere to the principle of least privilege.

    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

- When you are happy about the IAM policies added to your roles, click 'allow'
- Now you should get a screen with code snippets on how to authorise the SDK properly.

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:<your identitypool ID>',
});
```

Additionally, please read up on how to [stay safe on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html)

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If it didn't, please give me some feedback on how to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How one of the solutions you can use [Vault by HashiCorp](https://www.vaultproject.io) and store your AWS secrets here.
Anyone will see the only path to the secrets in the Vault instead of secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Becasue you are using the AWS SDK for JavaScript, read the official AWS Docs for using the AWS SDK for JavaScript and how to handle creds. See this topic in the D***eveloper Guide for JavaScript SDK Version 3***:

[Setting credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html)